# "No OpenID endpoint found" message lingers when switching providers

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, openid, error-message

MyOpenID was down for me earlier today. I was greeted with this message (freehand circles for your viewing pleasure):

[image: No OpenID endpoint found]

Next, I clicked on the StackExchange provider and found that the error message above lingers behind despite selecting a new and available provider.

[image: New OpenID provider with old error message]

Shouldn't the message be hidden unless the newly selected provider was also not found? That would be clearer to the user and prevent any confusion. Granted, this is a minor issue but it could be improved.

Comment: BTW, kudos to the SE team for the seamless experience when creating a new SE account and having my account automatically associated.